# How to fix popover position on Bootstrap slider?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-popover

How to fix popover position on Bootstrap slider don't move when screen size reduce?

The positions need to be fixed on the slides so when resizing they need to stay on the same position. For example, in the second slider, you see a white dot above the TV. This always needs to be above the TV, regardless of screen size.

This is online url: comfortica.nl

First popover

```
<div class="center1">
    <span class="qs">
        <span class="popover above">
            <p>Apparaten gaan varzelf uit</p>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center1 {
    margin-left: 51%;
    position: relative;
    top: -10%;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Add This i hope it will solve your `position.qs .popover p {width: 100%;}`

Comment: i am added but no solved it essue

Answer (score 0):

```
.center1 {
    // just to be able to see
    background:pink;
    // give 100% width to make it full screen
    // max-width will make it the larger size 
    width: 100%;
    max-width:680px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you might want to add: text-align:center;

Answer (score 0):

You can try the responsive layout. Load bootstrap-responsive.css and customize the style of "popover above" to fit in different screen sizes.

Comment: It uses the Bootstrap frame, so you will need to add both the boostrap.js and the css.

Comment: Also you need to add "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">" on top of your webpage and you need to define position one by one in different screen sizes.